# How to convert complex numbers back into "normal" numbers after performing FFT

Tags: python, numpy, fft

Say, I have an example signal consists of three cosines where each of which represents 4, 6 and 8 frequency band. Now, I throw this signal into frequency domain with the use of FFT, and in frequency domain I cut off unwantend 6 Hz band. Finally, I want to inverse the signal from the frequency domain back into time domain. But when I simply use `numpy.fft.ifft` I get array of complex numbers, which is not the best result for further analysis of the signal. How can I inverse FFT after performing bandpassing so I'll get whole information carried by real and imaginary part as one number? I looked into `z = sqrt(real^2 + imaginary^2)` thing, but it's not the "thing".

Below I provide a working example. I'll be grateful for your help.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fftfreq

# Define signal.
Fs = 128  # Sampling rate.
Ts = 1 / Fs  # Sampling interval.
Time = np.arange(0, 10, Ts)  # Time vector.
signal = np.cos(4*np.pi*Time) + np.cos(6*np.pi*Time) + np.cos(8*np.pi*Time)


def spectrum(sig, t):
    """
    Represent given signal in frequency domain.
    :param sig: signal.
    :param t: time scale.
    :return:
    """
    f = fftfreq(sig.size, d=t[1]-t[0])
    y = np.fft.fft(sig)
    return f, np.abs(y)


def bandpass(f, sig, min_freq, max_freq):
    """
    Bandpass signal in a specified by min_freq and max_freq frequency range.
    :param f: frequency.
    :param sig: signal.
    :param min_freq: minimum frequency.
    :param max_freq: maximum frequency.
    :return:
    """
    return np.where(np.logical_or(f < min_freq, f > max_freq), 0, sig)

freq, spec = spectrum(signal, Time)
signal_filtered = np.fft.ifft(bandpass(freq, spec, 5, 7))

print(signal_filtered)

"""
print(signal_filtered) result:

[  2.22833798e-15 +0.00000000e+00j   2.13212081e-15 +6.44480810e-16j
   1.85209996e-15 +1.23225456e-15j ...,   1.41336488e-15 -1.71179288e-15j
   1.85209996e-15 -1.23225456e-15j   2.13212081e-15 -6.44480810e-16j]
"""
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to cut out the frequencies between 5 and 7, 
then you'll want to keep frequencies where

```
(f < min_freq) | (f > max_freq)
```

which is equivalent to

```
np.logical_or(f < min_freq, f > max_freq)
```

Therefore, use

```
return np.where(np.logical_or(f < min_freq, f > max_freq), sig, 0)
```

instead of

```
return np.where(np.logical_or(f < min_freq, f > max_freq), 0, sig)
```

since the second argument to `np.where` contains the value returned by `np.where` when the condition is True.

With this one change, your code yields

```
[ 3.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j  2.96514652 +1.24442385e-15j
  2.86160515 +2.08976636e-15j ...,  2.69239924 +4.71763845e-15j
  2.86160515 +5.88163496e-15j  2.96514652 +6.82134642e-15j]
```

---

Note that if your signal is real, you could use `rfft` to take the discrete Fourier transform of a real sequence, and `irfft` to take its inverse, and `rfftfreq` to generate the frequencies.

For example,

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack as fftpack

# Define signal.
Fs = 128  # Sampling rate.
Ts = 1 / Fs  # Sampling interval.
Time = np.arange(0, 10, Ts)  # Time vector.
signal = np.cos(4*np.pi*Time) + np.cos(6*np.pi*Time) + np.cos(8*np.pi*Time)


def spectrum(sig, t):
    """
    Represent given signal in frequency domain.
    :param sig: signal.
    :param t: time scale.
    :return:
    """
    f = fftpack.rfftfreq(sig.size, d=t[1]-t[0])
    y = fftpack.rfft(sig)
    return f, np.abs(y)


def bandpass(f, sig, min_freq, max_freq):
    """
    Bandpass signal in a specified by min_freq and max_freq frequency range.
    :param f: frequency.
    :param sig: signal.
    :param min_freq: minimum frequency.
    :param max_freq: maximum frequency.
    :return:
    """
    return np.where(np.logical_or(f < min_freq, f > max_freq), sig, 0)

freq, spec = spectrum(signal, Time)
signal_filtered = fftpack.irfft(bandpass(freq, spec, 5, 7))

print(signal_filtered)
```

yields

```
[ 3.          2.96514652  2.86160515 ...,  2.69239924  2.86160515
  2.96514652]
```

Note you must use `scipy`'s `fftpack` here; do not mix SciPy's implementation with NumPy's.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a strictly real result (minus rounding error noise), the input to your IFFT needs to be hermician symmetric (e.g. you need to make sure the second half of the complex array is the complex conjugate mirror of the first half).  Look at your initial FFT of real data and you'll see the symmetry.

But it looks like you didn't filter the negative frequencies, and thus sent an unsymmetrical input to the IFFT which then outputs a complex result.